# select null value in query with c# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

I select with this query when `XuatKhoBOL.IDBTP = null` ,

`xuatkho.IDBTP == (XuatKhoBOL.IDBTP == 0 ? null : XuatKhoBOL.IDBTP)`

the result is incorrect but when I select with `xuatkho.IDBTP == null` the result is correct. Could anybody explain please?